# How can i indent text automatically when line is broken to 2 lines (or more) when responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple case where i have a question like this:

1) this is a very long text and i don't want to write everything here blah blah

Now when i start lower the resolution of the screen, i want to it to break like this:

1) this is a very long text and i don't

```
  want to write everything here blah blah
```

(indenting the second line to the right a bit)

instead of the ordinary one:

1) this is a very long text and i don't

want to write everything here blah blah

(not indented at all)

Very important note, i have no idea what is the length of the question, it is something dynamic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
p {
  text-indent: -1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

The `padding-left` causes the paragraph as a whole to be indented while the negative `text-indent` works on the first line to move it back to the initial starting point.

See this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvzwvjnL/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `text-indent: -10px;` to add negative indentation to the first line.
Every other line will be then indented comparing to the first one.